# Specify right margin in fixed positioning

Tags: css, positioning, css-position

I have no idea how to title this properly, but here is my problem:

I have this layout:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="content">this is my page</div>
    <div id="button">magic button</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
#button {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #f00;
  padding: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: 250px;

}

html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
#content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 700px;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
}​
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/n6UPF/

[image]

My page works just as I want it, the button is exactly where I want it to be.

**But** if I change the text on my button, it is no longer positioned properly.

I would like to position it "fixed" relative to the right edge of my content area.

Can this be done in pure CSS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If modifying the HTML is acceptable, you can use a wrapper:

```
<div id="button-wrapper">
    <div id="button">magic button</div>
</div>
```

```css
#button-wrapper {
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 350px;
    position: fixed;
}

#button {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

http://dabblet.com/gist/3740941

No, it's not really pretty, but...

Comment: yeah I think I prefer this semantics a bit http://dabblet.com/gist/3740961 one less id to worry about and the span kind of makes partial sense

Comment: Yeah, I actually hate this. Less because of the wrapper and more because of the `white-space: nowrap`. I don't think it's possible any other way though (but I'd be delighted if it were!).

Comment: Further proof that All CSS conundrums can be solved by adding more DIVs.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean...

```
#button
{
    position: fixed;
    right: 20px;
}
```

...or whatever distance you want on the right? Or something else?

Comment: Sorry maybe I was a bit unclear, I want the red buttons right edge to be 5px from the right edge of the grey border. no matter how much text is in the button. No matter how much resizing one does to the window.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question correctly, but could you not just use the `right` property instead of `left`?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/baKra/

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I run into trouble with exact positioning, it's because I haven't specified the width of my positioned element. The browser will try to calculate it itself, and that can throw things off.

Is there any way you can post what it looks like when it's no longer positioned properly?

Comment: I can not specify the width, I really don't know it, localization and dynamic content determine it.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if you are looking for the float:right property. 
Can you look at http://jsfiddle.net/n6UPF/1/ and see if that is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```css
#button {
position: fixed;
bottom: 20px;
background-color: #f00;
padding: 5px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: 250px;
}
```

to

```css
#button {
position: fixed;
bottom: 20px;
background-color: #f00;
padding: 5px;
right:20px
}
```

Comment: see minitechs answer for the exact behavior I am after. try editing the text, resizing the window and see what happens